# MANIFEST.in installs file to site-packages/VERSION rather than site-packages/mypackage/VERSION

Tags: python, setuptools, python-3.6

I'm trying get the file `VERSION` in the root of my python package installed into so that I can read from this file once it's installed, however using MANIFEST.in, the file is placed in the top-level `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` rather than inside of `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mypackage`.

I'm trying to do this so that I can display the packages version at runtime and also easily make use of it inside of the repo.

directory structure:

```
setup.py
MANIFEST.in
VERSION
mypackage/
  - __init__.py
  - __main__.py
  - foo.py
```

`MANIFEST.in`:

```
include VERSION
```

`setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("VERSION", "r") as versionFile:
  version = versionFile.read().strip()

setup(
  name="mypackage",
  version=version,
  packages=find_packages(),
  include_package_data=True)
```

`mypackage/__main__.py`:

```
...
  verFile = pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "VERSION")
  with open(verFile, "r") as fin:
    version = str(fin.read().strip())
  print(version)
...
```

How can I get the `VERSION` file to install inside of the package directory?

Comment: why don't you just move it into the package directory?

Comment: @wim I'd really like to mirror the structure of all of my other projects (mostly CMake) where `VERSION` sits at the root of the repo. I could also have setup.py copy it there before `setup()` is called, but I'm hoping theres a cleaner solution to this.